# Laravel Polymorphic Relations Has Many Through

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, has-many-through

I have a `Subscriber` model

```
// Subscriber Model

id
user_id
subscribable_id
subscribable_type

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function subscribable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

And a `Topic` model

```
// Topic Model

public function subscribers()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Subscriber', 'subscribable');
}
```

And I want to get all users through `Subscriber` model, to notify them like

`Notification::send($topic->users, new Notification($topic));`

```
// Topic Model


public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Subscriber');
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you may want to use a pivot table for this use case?

Comment: Any example please?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: what is the error when you call `$topic->users`?

Answer (score 86):

```php
// Topic Model

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Subscriber', 'subscribable_id')
        ->where(
            'subscribable_type', 
            array_search(static::class, Relation::morphMap()) ?: static::class
        );
}
```

Polymorphic `hasManyThrough` relationships are the same as any others, but with an added constraint on the `subscribable_type`, which can be retrieved from the `Relation::morphMap()` array, or by using the class name directly.

Comment: The answer assumes a different relationship model to the one in question. `hasManyThrough` would require subscriber ID to be present in the users table.

Comment: Great answer. You can also do `$this->getMorphClass()` to avoid the array search.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Matt's approach, the following code also could be another solution:

```
//Topic Model
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'subscribers', 'subscribale_id', 'user_id')
        ->where('subscribale_type', static::class);
}
```

In this way `Subscriber` treated as a pivot table and second argument is table name for pivot.

> The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to. Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Consider the `where` clause after `belongsToMany` to filter only the current model.

Answer (score 12):

What you're after is not `hasManyThrough`, but `morphedByMany`.

`hasManyThrough` is useful when you have `A` one-to-many `B`, `B` one-to-many `C`, and you want to use `A` to fetch many `C`.

What you have is a polymorphic pivot table sitting in the middle between `A` and `C`.

```
// Topic Model

public function users()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\User', 'subscribable', 'pivot/subscriber_table_name');
}
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: Why do you think he has a "polymorphic pivot table sitting in the middle" which assumes a polymorphic many to many? It looks more like a polymorphic one to many.

Comment: @digout To me it seems like a typical scenario where a single user can be subscribed to many topics and a single topic can be followed by many users.

Answer (score 5):

try this package
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

then you could use it like this:

```
class Topic extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
            'App\User',
            ['App\Subscriber'],
            [null, ['subscribable_type', 'subscribable_id']]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that package! It's seems very powerful, saved lot of my time.