# How can I mock a different model to retrieve a polymorphic relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, polymorphism

I have 3 data models, one of which extends the other:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Opinion extends Model
{
    public function reactions()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Reaction', 'reactable');
    }

    ...
}
```

```
namespace App\Models\Activity;

use App\Models\Opinion;

class ActivityOpinion extends Opinion
{
    ...
}
```

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Reaction extends Model
{
    public function reactable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    ...
}
```

The `App\Models\Opinion` model has a polymorphic relationship with the `App\Models\Reaction` model. I can retrieve all of the `App\Models\Opinion` reactions no problem, so I know the relationship works great.

My question is, how can I retrieve the same set of reactions from the `App\Models\Activity\ActivityOpinion` model? Because right now, it is looking for `App\Models\Activity\ActivityOpinion` as the relationship but I need it to look for `App\Models\Opinion`. Is it possible to mock another model in a polymorphic relationship?

Comment: so you want the opinions from ActivityOpinion through Reaction  right ?

Comment: if that's your goal take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43285779/laravel-polymorphic-relations-has-many-through

Comment: @AhmedAboud Not exactly I want to get the Reaction of Opinion from ActivityOpinion which is extended from Opinion. So when I call `reactions()` from ActivityOpinion it will query for `App\Models\Opinion` in the `reactable_type` field instead of `App\Models\Activity\ActivityOpinion`

Answer (score 0):

This is because in a Polymorphic Relationship in the stored data (if leaved as default) the relationship type gets the class namespace (sort of) to specify wich model needs to be returned. That's why when you try to access to your `reactions()` relationship from `ActivityOpinion`  it will look up for the `App\ActivityOpinion` value in the `reactable_type`.

You can customize the morph class to search in the model addind this:

**Opinion.php**

```
protected $morphClass = 'reaction';
```

This should be enough, if not, add it also in the `ActivityOpinion` model.

---

### Note

This could breake some things when trying to search results using Eloquent. Check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27993113/7117697) in order to address this possible inconviniance.

---

---

## Update

I've just found out that you could do all this even easier with [MorphMap](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types). From the docs:

> ### Custom Polymorphic Types
>
> By default, Laravel will use the fully qualified class name to store
>   the type of the related model. For instance, given the one-to-many
>   example above where a `Comment` may belong to a `Post` or a `Video`,
>   the default `commentable_type` would be either `App\Post` or
>   `App\Video,` respectively. However, you may wish to decouple your
>   database from your application's internal structure. In that case, you
>   may define a "morph map" to instruct Eloquent to use a custom name for
>   each model instead of the class name:
>
> ```
> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
>
> Relation::morphMap([
>     'posts' => 'App\Post',
>     'videos' => 'App\Video',
> ]);
> ```
>
> You may register the `morphMap` in the `boot` function of your
>   `AppServiceProvider` or create a separate service provider if you
>   wish.

Comment: I already looked into `morphMap` as a solution for this, but my understanding is that you can't have 2 models morphed to one.

Comment: That is because you are extending one from the other, but the thing is that you are trying to get the results from one in the other model. Maybe you should structure your table a little bit diferent to get your desired output (a field `type`maybe).