# Laravel polymorphic relationship with additional table for type

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, relationship

Laravel uses string for polymorphic types (`App\Post`, `App\Video`, ...).
Table structure from official documentation ([Many To Many (Polymorphic)](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)):

```
posts
    id - integer
    name - string

videos
    id - integer
    name - string

tags
    id - integer
    name - string

taggables
    tag_id - integer
    taggable_id - integer
    taggable_type - string
```

But my existing table structure looks like this:

```
posts
    id - integer
    name - string

videos
    id - integer
    name - string

tags
    id - integer
    name - string

taggable_types
    id - integer
    name - string

taggables
    tag_id - integer
    taggable_id - integer
    taggable_type_id - integer
```

so in the `taggables` table, the `taggable_type` field is replaced with `taggable_type_id`.
How can I implement polymorphic with a type that has its own table (`taggable_types`), so inside taggables table (using `taggable_type_id` instead of `taggable_type` for the field)?

Comment: have you tried the top answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43285779/laravel-polymorphic-relations-has-many-through