# hasManyThrough with morph

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, polymorphic-relationship

I have a projects table that either can be assigned to a user or a team, this is the structure:

```
id
assignable_id
assignable_type

class Project extends Model {
    public function assignable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

and my team table contains members with a pivot table:

```
id

class Team extends Model {

    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    public function projects(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Project::class, 'assignable');
    }
}

// team_user table
team_id
user_id
```

and finally my user table:

```
id

class User extends Model {

    public function teams(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
    }

    public function projects(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Project::class, 'assignable');
    }
}
```

Now the problem is I want to get all projects that have been assigned to a user either directly or through a team, as expected $user()->projects return the ones that directly have been assigned to the user.

I tried many solutions but none has worked for me yet.

Comment: You didnt use `Relation::morphMap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you actually need something like this:

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Project', 'App\User', 'assignable_id')
        ->where(
            'assignable_type', 
            array_search(static::class, Relation::morphMap()) ?: static::class
        );
}
```

or

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class, 'assignable', 'assignable_id', 'project_id')
        ->where('assignable_type', static::class);
}
```

Ref: [Laravel Polymorphic Relations Has Many Through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43285779/laravel-polymorphic-relations-has-many-through)

Your working solution:

```
public function projects() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Project::class,
        User::class,
        'id',
        'assignable_id',
    )->where(
        'assignable_type', User::class
    )->orWhere(function ($q) {
        $q->where('assignable_type', Team::class)
        ->whereIn('assignable_id', $this->teams->pluck('id'));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but that did not work, first, there is no mention of the team, and second, the first code was wrong because it looks for assignable_id on the users table and the second one looks for the assignable table in DB.

Comment: You have to change foreign_key references in this code of course. If you have your code on git i can assist. @MohammadZahed

Comment: I did customize it and added 'id' before 'assignable_id' in the first code but the result did not include team's project it was the same as $this->morphMany(Project::class, 'assignable');

Comment: By the way, thanks for the gesture but it is not on git yet, it is a new project but if you think it is necessary I can give you access!

Comment: i dont mind taking a look. just add `djokicpn`

Comment: I added you to the repository.

Comment: @MohammadZahed check issue tab on github

Comment: I just updated my answer and git repo :) @MohammadZahed

Answer (score 1):

Use `whereHasMorph`:

```
$user = ...

$projects = Project::whereHasMorph(
    'assignable',
    [Team::class, User::class],
    function ($query, $type) use($user) {
        if($type === Team::class){
            $query->whereRelation('users', 'id', $user->id);
        }else{
            $query->where('id', $user->id);
        } 
    }
)->get();
```

Or split into 2 queries and merge together:

```
$projects = $user->projects;
$teams = $user->teams()->with('projects')->get();
$teams_projects = $teams->pluck('projects')->collapse();
$projects = $projects->merge($teams_projects);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I did something like this but the problem is I want the response to be a Relation response that I can return from the model.